# Adding a to a counter depending on select option value

Tags: jquery

I have a number of `select` inputs, all with the two `options`, 'yes' and 'no'.

Every time the 'yes' option is selected, I want to add 1 to a counter. I can do this with the code below.

However, if the user changes the value to 'no' and then back to 'yes' then the counter will be on 2 instead of 1, which isn't wanted.

How do i prevent this so that if they click 'yes' it adds 1, and they then change to 'no' it removes 1. But if they click no first, it remains the same?

```
    var counter = 0;

    jQuery("select#select1").change(function(){
        var variable1 = jQuery(this).children("option:selected").val();
        if (variable1 == 'yes') {
            counter++;
            alert("Counter:" + counter);
        } else {
            alert("Counter:" + counter);
        }
    });

    jQuery("select#select2").change(function(){
        var variable2 = jQuery(this).children("option:selected").val();
        if (variable2 == 'yes') {
            counter++;
            alert("Counter:" + counter);
        } else {
            alert("Counter:" + counter);
        }
    });

    jQuery("select#select3").change(function(){
        var variable3 = jQuery(this).children("option:selected").val();
        if (variable3 == 'yes') {
            counter++;
            alert("Counter:" + counter);
        } else {
            alert("Counter:" + counter);
        }
    });
```

In this example, the counter should never be able to go higher than 3, as there are only 3 `select` fields. (My attempt to resolve problem this was to add the `else` and have -1, but this as dumb)

Comment: FYI, to get the value you can just use `$(this).val()`.

Comment: Don't use the counter variable. When you need the count, just use a loop that counts the number of selects that are set to `yes`

Comment: Perfect with the value suggestion Barmar, thanks! But if i use `counter--` and they first select they choose 'no', that will set the counter to -1. The counter should just count the number of `select` fields with 'yes', whic will be either 0, 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: That's why I deleted that comment.

Comment: Yeah, Barmar, I just saw you deleted, im a slow typer haha. How do I go about creating the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't update the counter variable when they select from the menu. When you need the counter, use a loop that counts the number of selects that have the value `yes`.

```js
function get_count() {
  var counter = 0;
  $("select").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "yes") {
      counter++;
    }
  });
  return counter;
}

$("#show").click(function() {
  alert(get_count());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Option 1:
<select id="select1">
  <option value="">Please choose</option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<br> Option 2:
<select id="select2">
  <option value="">Please choose</option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<br> Option 3:
<select id="select3">
  <option value="">Please choose</option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<br>
<button id="show">Show count</button>
```

Anywhere that you were previously reading the `counter` variable, replace that with `get_count()` and it will calculate it based on the current selections.

Comment: Hey, does this take into account when a `select` field is changed? Or will this just always be 0 as that is what counter is when the page loads?

Comment: You do this every time you need the counter, not just once.

Comment: I've turned it into a function. So instead of using the variable, use `get_count()`

Comment: Thanks Barmar, and at what point do i call the function?

Comment: At the same points you were previously using the variable.

Comment: Sorry, im confused. Will this not have the same issue if a user selects 'yes' and then changes that same select to a 'no' and then back again to a 'yes'. Will that still add 2 to the counter instead of 1?

Comment: You're not adding anything when the user selects. When you need the total count, you calculate it on the fly.